# Spring JPA bidirectional relation on multiple nested entities

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I know there has been multiple questions on bidirectional relations using spring jpa in the past but my case is a little bit different because i am using 3 entities with 2 relationships to implement a medical system

I have 3 entities : doctor/patient/appointment

here is the code for the 3 entities
please note all setters , getters and constructors implemented but ommited here for clarity

**Patient class**

```
@Entity
public class resPatient {
@Id
@GeneratedValue( strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY )
private long code;
private String name;
private String gender;
private String email;
private String mobile;
private int age;

private String notes;


@OneToMany(mappedBy = "patient")
List<resPackageMembership> memberships;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "patient")
List<resAppointment> appointments;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy = "patient")
List<resMedImage> medImages;
```

**Doctor class**

```
 @Entity
 public class resDoctor {

@Id
@GeneratedValue( strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY )
private long code;
private String name;
private String mobile;



private String email;
private String gender;
private int age;
private  String speciality;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "doctor")
List<resAppointment> appointments;
```

**Appointment class**

```
@Entity
public class resAppointment {

@Id
@GeneratedValue( strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY )
private long code;
private String speciality;
@Basic
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date dateCreated;


@Basic
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date dateToVisit;
private String status;
private String notes;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "doctorCode")
private resDoctor doctor;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "patientCode")
private resPatient patient;
```

the way my medical system should work is that when i get a patient using my restful controller i want all the patient data including his appointments but this leads to an infinite loop as the appointment has the doctor which also has appointments and so on.

i cannot user @JSONIGNORE as there are 2 relationships i want to get the patient with his appointments which should have the doctor without the appointments array and should not have any patient data as i already am in the patient object

Comment: the object i get when is
{
    "code": 1,
    "name": "ahmed ali mohamed",
    "age": 22,
    "notes": "high blood pressure",
    "memberships": [],
    "appointments": [
        {
            "code": 1,
            "speciality": "laser",
    
            "doctor": {
                "code": 3,
                "name": "mohamed khalafalla",
                "mobile": "012",
                "gender": "male",
                "age": 22,
                "speciality": "heart",
                "appointments": [
                    {

Answer (score 1):

As a general best-practice, it's recommended to separate the entities from the data transfer objects used for the rest controllers. With DTO's in place, you have more control on which data to include and serialize within them to avoid the circlular references.
If you like check out https://bootify.io, it generates the DTOs from your database schema, but the custom endpoint you still need to define/build.

Answer (score 1):

I develop an annotation processor called [beanknife](https://github.com/vipcxj/beanknife) recently, it support generate DTO from any class. You need config by annotation. But you don't need change the original class. This library support configuring on a separate class. Of course you can choose which property you want and which you not need. And you can add new property by the static method in the config class. For your question:

```
// this will generate a DTO class named "resPatientView". 
// You can change this name using genName attribute.
@ViewOf(value=resPatient.class, includePattern = ".*")
public class PatientViewConfigure {
    // here tell the processor to automatically convert the property appointments from List<resAppointment> to List<resAppointmentWithoutPatient>. 
    // resAppointmentWithoutPatient is the generated class configured at the following. 
    // Note, although at this moment it not exists and your idea think it is an error. 
    // this code really can be compiled, and after compiled, all will ok.
    @OverrideViewProperty("appointments")
    private List<resAppointmentWithoutPatient> appointments;
}

// here generated a class named resAppointmentWithoutPatient whick has all properties of resAppointment except patient
@ViewOf(value=resAppointment.class, genName="resAppointmentWithoutPatient", includePattern = ".*", excludes={"patient"})
public class AppointmentWithoutPatientViewConfigure {
    // the doctor property will be converted to its dto version which defined by the configure class DoctorWithoutAppointmentsViewConfigure.
    @OverrideViewProperty("doctor")
    private resDoctorWithoutAppointments doctor;
}

// here we generate a class which has all properties of resDoctor except appointments
@ViewOf(value=resDoctor.class, genName="resDoctorWithoutAppointments", includePattern = ".*", excludes={"appointments"})
public class DoctorWithoutAppointmentsViewConfigure {}

// in you rest controller. return the dto instead of the entities.
resPatient patient = ...
resPatientView dto = resPatientView.read(patient);
List<resPatient> patients = ...
List<resPatientView> dto = resPatientView.read(patients);
```

At the end, the class resPatientView will has the same shap with resPatient except its appointments not having patient property and its doctor property is replaced with a version without appointments property.

Here are more [examples](https://github.com/vipcxj/beanknife/tree/master/beanknife-examples/src/main/java/io/github/vipcxj/beanknife/cases/beans).
The version 1.10 is ready. Will fix some bug and support the configure bean to be managed by spring.

Comment: Great Work ! Thank you